# Watching, setting and getting active language in Windows using events

Tags: windows, events, localization

I want to have control over the active input language in Windows 7. I want to be able to set it, get it, and be notified when it changes.

Can I use Windows events, like those recorded by Process Monitor, to achieve this? Is there a specific event I should filter to in order to see these events?

**Update**: If you provide code, I prefer Python if possible.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the pointer Hans. I'm a bit lost as to how to use this. Can you explain?

Comment: @HansPassant After reading about it further, I see that this message was deprecated. I think now we're supposed to use TSF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629032(v=vs.85).aspx However I can't figure out how to use it. (I've never done Windows development.) Anyone care to explain in an answer?

Comment: It is not "deprecated", the .NET InputLanguageChanged event depends on it.  The text services api is a COM rabbit hole in which many programmers were lost, never to be seen again.  Having a window respond to a message is a very basic programming task in Windows, it is completely unclear what kind of help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  The message you want is: WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE

Here is an example in python with pywin32:

```
def edit_proc(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
  if msg == win32con.WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
    print 'User changed the input language'
```

Basically what you're doing is setting up a WndProc function, which designates a function to receive messages for a given Window:

```
 self.old_edit_proc = win32gui.SetWindowLong(self.edit_hwnd,
                                                    win32con.GWL_WNDPROC,
                                                    self.edit_proc)
```

This example comes from here: http://auralbits.blogspot.com/2014/02/a-native-win32-application-in-python.html

Comment: I've checked out the page, but it seems to talk about building your own app and controls. I don't want to do that. I want to listen to language changes in all applications, and be able to change the language. How can I do that?

Comment: I misunderstood.  For that I think you need to use hooks.  But I don't have much experience with that so I can't help you further.